# Other people can't stop Designer workflows I start, even though they have full control

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

Users in a group with Full Control on the list get access errors when trying to stop workflows created in SharePoint Designer that I started. I have Full Control access as well.  I have no problem stopping workflows started by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have permission on the site?

If we want to end the workflow for the items, we need at least Edit permission on the site.

Here is a [MS link on the subject of permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fUnderstanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848) - as you see, a group e.g. 'Edit' is comprised of a number of individual permissions, including '**Manage Lists**'.  By adding a user to the Edit group, they should be able to stop the workflow.

[image: permissions - manage lists]